# syntax error: expected $, found name "authprovider"

Tags: react-native, apollo-client, graphcool

I am running sample app. I called mutation for createUser in graphcool. But i am getting error like below screenshot.
here is my code

```
  this.props
      .createUser({
        variables: {
          email: this.state.email,
          password: this.state.password
        }
      })
      .then(({ data }) => {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert('There is a problem ' + error)
      })

const CREATE_USER = gql`
  mutation createUser(authProvider:{email:{$email: String, $password: String}}) {
    createUser(email: $email, password: $password) {
      id
      email
      password
    }
  }
`
const RegisterData = compose(graphql(CREATE_USER, { name: 'createUser' }))(Register)
```

export default RegisterData

here is my screenshot:
  [image]